# How do you do frame-rate tests on a console?

Tags: framerate

For 6th/7th/8th generation consoles, how do I do frame-rate tests, for an example, like this DigitalFoundry video?

Comment: They have specialized hardware for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since console games are closed off to development/back-end analysis tools (such as a console you would find in a PC game), your only option to find the frame rate is using external hardware that directly interacts with your console or outputting video from your console to your computer for analysis by a special type of video software.

Comment: How would I do that? Would I somehow check the refresh rate of the monitor connected with my console and transfer it to my PC?

Comment: The monitor you use with your console doesn't matter for this process, but you just need it obviously to see what you're doing on the console. The video needs to be output directly to your PC also so you'd need a splitter to output to both.